# Fiddler regex to replace url

Tags: regex, fiddler

I'm trying to find and replace urls with fiddler.

Example urls:

**helpful.ninja/admin/js/1/1.js**

**helpful.ninja/admin/css/1/1/1.css**

Now I would want the regex to grab any folder structure behind the admin/ and replace the url like:

**dev.helpful.ninja/admin/**

So the output should look like:

**dev.helpful.ninja/admin/css/1/1/1.css** and 
**dev.helpful.ninja/admin/js/1/1.js**

I tried something like

```
regex:^http\:\/\/www\.helpful\.ninja\/admin\/((.+)\.(xml|json|js|css|png|jpeg|jpg|gif|jhtml))$
```

and to replace it with

```
http://dev.helpful.ninja/admin/$1
```

---

Sadly it won't work out does any have a idea what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: You specify `http://www.` but your sample strings do not contain those. Remove and see [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/sC0zP5/2).

Comment: Couldnt add http://www. cause im only allowed to post 1 url in here

Comment: Then [I cannot repro](https://regex101.com/r/sC0zP5/3).

Answer (score 0):

Use the following RegEx:

```
^http:\/\/www\.helpful\.ninja\/admin\/(.+\.(xml|json|js|css|png|jpeg|jpg|gif|jhtml))$
```

Check out [This Demo](https://regex101.com/r/zV9hT5/1)